# When to ask for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on android 6.0 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

My app requires `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions to work with user's images on demand, that are located in non app-specific folder. So I'm wondering when should I ask for granted permission, before opening screen/service that will start File I/O operations?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f17qe9vZ8RM) from I/O that talks about some best practices.

If using these permissions is required for the core functionality of your app then you should request them following a warm welcome when the app is first loaded. If it's secondary functionality that some users might never encounter, then it's better to do so only after the user tries to use that functionality.